# Caching selected URLs with Varnish

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

Is there a way to provide a static list of URLs to cache? I know that I can put a bunch of 'if' statements in the VCL but I am wondering if there is a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put them to regular expression

```
if (req.url ~ "^/(some/url/1|some/url/2|....|some/urlN)") {
    unset req.http.Cookie;
    return (lookup);
}
else {
    return (pass);
}
```

or just list with ||

```
    if (req.url ~ "^/some/url/1"
    || req.url ~ "^/some/url/2
    ...
    || req.url ~ "^/some/urlN"
    ) {
            unset req.http.Cookie;
            return (lookup);
    }
```

Comment: Or even better, make the backend reply with proper cache headers and the extra logic isn't needed in varnish but in the application where it belongs.

Comment: I actually used || approach, but still think it would be nice to have something more efficient, like a hash table to lookup the URL.